# Entity Framework n to n relationship add object to another object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, blazor, repository

**I have a Model with Clients:**

```
public class Client

{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? Hostname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Software>? Softwares { get; set; }

}
```

**And a Model with Software:**

```
public class Software
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Client>? Clients { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is supposed to be an n to n connection. How can I add software to my clients?**

**What I've tried:**

```
public async void add(Software software)
        {
            using (var repo = new ClientRepository(contextFactory.CreateDbContext()))
            {
                client.Softwares.Add(software);
                await repo.Save(client);
            }
```

**Repository:**

```
public async Task Save(Client client)
        {
            _context.Clients.Update(client);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        }
```

This works for the first software I add, but gives me the following error if I try to add a second one:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ClientSoftware'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ClientSoftware'. The
> duplicate key value is (7003, 5002).

Comment: @viveknuna That should be handled by EF

Comment: @Herbix why dont you have `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in `Client` class?

Comment: @viveknuna I noticed that too and added it, still not working tho

Comment: @Herbix are you using code first or DB first approach?

Comment: @viveknuna code first

Comment: then have you added migration and updated the database after making the code changes?

Comment: @viveknuna yeah, same thing

Comment: Just for sanity, are you sure you are not actually trying to add a software for a client where the client already has the software?

Comment: @topsail nope, checked the data, also I figured out that it always works the first time I do it on a new Client. Create a Client, add 1 software, it work. As soon as I try to add a second one, it gives me the error

Comment: Add another ... of the same software? Or a different software? Surely the message must change at least in the detail of what the keys are that are violating constraints?

Comment: @topsail a different software, but it gives me the error as if it tried to add the same software as the first time.

Comment: That may be a problem in your coding logic, not the relationships then.

Comment: @topsail it must be a problem in my repo. I think it is trying the dbcontext doesn't dispose correctly and tries to do the same thing again

Comment: @HenkHolterman no, its a software that already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: Do you make a new one with new() every time?

> A: no, its a software that already exists

Then that is the error.
The first SaveChanges() will start tracking it as Existing. You can check: The Id will be != 0.

When you then later add it to the same Client you'll get the duplicate error.

So somewher in your code:

```
  await add(software);       // existing
  software = new Software(); // add this
```

Related, change:

```
public async void add(Software software)
```

to

```
public async Task Add(Software software)
```

Always avoid `async void`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding more than one relation of the same. Before adding software to a client, make sure a relation does not exist yet, then you can go ahead and add software to client.

Also, you can improve your entities. Use better naming for the primary keys and add `[Key]` attribute to `Software` class as well.

`Client`:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Softwares = new HashSet<Software>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
}
```

`Software`:

```cs
public class Software
{
    public Software()
    {
        Clients = new HashSet<Client>();
    }
    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SoftwareId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Check if relation already exists:

```cs
// Get the client including its related softwares
var client = dbContext.Clients.Include(x => x.Softwares)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Hostname == "Ibrahim");


if (client != null)
{
    // Check with unique property such as name of software
    // If it does not exist in this current client, then add software
    if (!client.Softwares.Any(x => x.Name == software.Name))
        client.Softwares.Add(software);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note: If you update your entities, remember to create new migration and database.

Comment: Followed all your steps, still not working

Comment: @Herbix Did you get same error or a different one? Share the error if not same. Also note, the code in my answer I actually implemented it on my side to save `software` to `client`.